# How to avoid aptana to detect getter and setter as errors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, validation, aptana, jslint

I have this code:

```
function A(){}
A.prototype = {
    set a(v){},
    get a(){return}
};
```

Aptana detects an error at this line ***set a(v){},*** but it works on modern browsers.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Note that this syntax still does not work in MSIE 8. It isn't a "modern browser" by any means, but it is still used by quite a few people.

Comment: MSIE is in version 10, and MSIE 8 is 5.8% of users (http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp#gsc.tab=0), also microsoft it self in some pages request users to upgrade.

Comment: Those statistics are not representative — they only count visitors to w3schools, not the Internet as a whole.

Comment: :} All statistics are so close to that numbers. In the worst case scenario, it is MSIE 8 is 12%. To those users we offer chrome, fire fox and MSIE 10. We dont like old code, old browsers and twice the work. Join us dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aptana currently does not recognize the `get` and `set` keywords used to define getters and setters in JavaScript. There is no way for you to fix this, however, there is a way you can work around it. Aptana natively uses JSLint for JavaScript validation, and allows you filter out warnings and errors that you may not care about.

The errors that it is picking up on that line are:

> Expected an operator and instead saw '{'.
>    Expected ':' and instead saw 'a'.

You can tell Aptana to ignore these by going to **Preferences** -> **Aptana Studio** -> **Validation**, selecting the **JSLint** validator, and adding those errors to the list of errors and warnings to be filtered from validation (you can use the entire error string or some regex).

**Warning**: You may not want to ignore these errors, as they are Syntax Errors and will cause your JavaScript to bomb out when it loads if you miss them.

Comment: I believe you can just do `* instead saw '{'` and `Expected ':' *`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I'm out of aptana validations, I just turn of that part THX